# Mourre Theory: Resolvent Formula

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Problem**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a Hamiltonian:
$$H:\mathcal{D}(H)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad H=H^*$$

Denote its resolvent by:
$$z\in\rho(H):\quad R(z):=(z-H)^{-1}$$

Introduce its adjoint as:
$$A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad\mathrm{ad}(A):=i[H,A]\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$$

Then one has the formula:
$$\mathrm{ad}^n(A)\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad[R(z)^n,A]=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}(-i)^kR(z)^k\mathrm{ad}^k(A)R(z)^n$$
How to check this formally?

**Attempt**

Domain issues don't arise as:
$$\mathrm{ad}(A)\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad A\mathcal{D}(H)\subseteq\mathcal{D}(H)$$

The induction starts by:
$$[R(z),A]\varphi=R(z)A(z-H)R(z)\varphi-R(z)(z-H)AR(z)\varphi\\
=-R(z)AHR(z)\varphi+R(z)HAR(z)\varphi=(-i)R(z)\mathrm{ad}(A)R(z)\varphi$$
But I fail to set up the induction step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula seems wrong:
$$[R(z)^2,A]=R(z)[R(z),A]+[R(z),A]R(z)
\\=(-i)R(z)^2\mathrm{ad}(A)R(z)+(-i)R(z)\mathrm{ad}(A)R(z)^2
\\=(-i)R(z)\mathrm{ad}(A)R(z)^2+(-i)R(z)[R(z),A]R(z)+(-i)R(z)\mathrm{ad}(A)R(z)^2
\\=(-i)R(z)\mathrm{ad}(A)R(z)^2+(-i)^2R(z)^2\mathrm{ad}(A)R(z)^2+(-i)R(z)\mathrm{ad}(A)R(z)^2
\\=2(-i)R(z)\mathrm{ad}(A)R(z)^2+(-i)^2R(z)^2\mathrm{ad}^2(A)R(z)^2
\\\neq\sum_{k=1}^2\binom{2}{k}(-i)^kR(z)^k\mathrm{ad}^k(A)R(z)^2$$
*(Maybe I missed something, did I?)*